Why do calculus and mathematical analysis study sequences specifically?
A sequence is a special kind of function where the domain is the set of positive integers. Why can’t we merge the study of sequences into the general study of functions to cover properties like convergence, divergence, and boundedness? I notice that in many books, theorems and properties discussed for sequences are revisited later for general functions f(x). This seems somewhat repetitive. It must be intentional to discuss sequences as a separate topic, so what is the purpose?
The reason I’m asking this question is that I don’t want to learn each chapter’s material in isolation. Instead, I hope to find connections among the different parts and understand the relationships between them.

I suppose the main reason to treat sequences separately is that there are phenomena that exist for sequences but not really for general functions. For example, there are many tests that one can use in the hope of determining whether a sequence converges; on the other hand, I don't know of many tests that one can use to determine whether a function has a limit.

Also, the standard approach in analysis is to define the real numbers in terms of Cauchy sequences. So there's some kind of bootstrapping happening: while you could subsume limits of sequences in a general discussion of, say, continuity of functions between metric spaces, this only makes sense after you've constructed the real numbers and established their basic properties.
